# Two different measures with equal support

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Can there be two different complex (hence finite) measures whose support is equal? I presume no, as it may defy some separation theorems otherwise. But I need a concrete proof. Any help is hugely appreciated !

Comment: Multiply one measure by some density which is bounded from away and bounded away from zero.

Comment: What is your definition of support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support of a measure $\mu$ is the complement of the largest open set $U$ with $\mu (U)=0$. If $f$ and $g$ are strictly positive integrable functions on $\mathbb R$ and $\mu (A)=\int_A f(x)dx,\nu (A)=\int_A g(x)dx$ then  the support of  either measure is $\mathbb R$ (because the only open set $U$ of measure $0$ is the empty set). Take $f(x)=e^{-|x|}, g(x)=e^{-2|x|}$, for example to get a counterexample.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you very much for your response. But what if the measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ have compact supports? Is the statement true then?

Comment: To modfy the abve example just redefine $f$ and $g$ to $0$ outside $[0,1]$. You willget two $\mu$ and $\nu$ both with  support exctly $[0,1]$.